# Git push failing for particular branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I am using remote git repository (remote present on self hosted gitlab)
i am able to take pull and push my code on all the branched except 1 (say: branchX)
getting following error:

```
Counting objects: 88, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (88/88), 422.63 KiB | 140.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 88 (delta 68), reused 54 (delta 39)
remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To https://gitlab.xxx/xxx.git
 ! [remote rejected]   branchX -> branchX (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.xxx/xxx.git'
```

I tried `git repack` but it did not help.  I know my remote repo has been currupted due to some reason but i guess that issue should not stop me from pushing the code from my local to a newly created repo. Please help me to solve this issue so that i can pushh my code to new repo

Comment: Can you ssh on your gitlab server and run `git fsck` on your central repository ?

Comment: git ssh never works for me i connect via https

Comment: git fsck output...

Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (25014/25014), done.
dangling blob 43016ef8bcd5e6275d09e3667c54249e84366b05
dangling blob 3b08c994fa3d7dfbd6c606e432570887fb6382e3
dangling blob df0a46f2ac82778dc7214e20d38fc6ed61a77111
dangling blob 060fb3f47aeca668e6cd35bf86474c9a1d1517e2
dangling blob 4b15c1e4f5c1dfc8c20c306361140a1310f93e13
....
dangling blob 48f8940957468357a34fe94e2fa87abe10d195df
dangling blob 6ffde17757035098ccc4ea8c307ccafccd95312b
dangling blob adff042ab1e93b6820b8177da78831d11d62b30b

Comment: ah yes, I had forgotten gitlab allows you to run it through its gui :) dangling blobs (or dangling trees, or dangling commits) are not a problem. Do you have lines that mention something other than "dangling something" ? Please paste those lines in your question.

Comment: nothing else than dangling blobs

Comment: ok, that's good news actually : your remote repo is not corrupted. Could it be that the disk on your gitlab server is full ? (from [this help page on Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/error-unpack-failed-unpack-objects-abnormal-exit-779171795.html))

Comment: in that case why i am able to puch to other branched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216622/discussion-between-shubhangi-singh-and-legec).

Comment: @LeGEC can you please help me with this issue i have added more information to my question